# Ability to set parent div style when substituting in a child component

Tags: angular

I have a set of angular pages which substitute in child pages depending on what menu items are selected. The main index contains the navbar, and a div (with a css class `card` into which the router slots child elements into).

Typically this card has a margin-top of ~25px to keep child elements away from the navbar, and to keep page layout looking sensible for the 95% of pages displayed.

If I wanted to have a page without the margins embeded, how would I go about overriding the parents CSS in the subcomponent? Declaring an extension to the class as follows:

```
.jh-card {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

ends up with the `_ngcontent-...` qualifier being added (as would be expected). How would i go about overriding the parents class instead of the components class itself?

Comment: I am not sure If what you need is to use the `ViewEncapulation` property on the child component. Can you give more details? Maybe the code from the components?

Comment: You are indeed correct - Setting ViewEncapsulation to NONE stops angular adding the style encapsulation, and solves the issue. Many thanks!